# How to change refresh rate without changing resolution to low resolution mode on MacOS Venture13.4.1

Tags: macos, display, resolution, refresh

I have a LG IPS MP77 monitor and trying to use it as my external monitor on my MacBook M1 which runs Venture13.4.1. I connected them with a HDMI cable and at first it shows that refreshment rate is exceeded. Then I found that it is because the monitor only support refreshment rate between 30-83kHz, but the 25kHz refreshment is the only option that has been shown on the display option.

I have looked up the issue online and found that if I choose the resolution 1980x1080(low resolution) then 50kHz and 60kHz options for the refreshment rate shows up. However the result is unacceptable as words and picture are hard to see. I have tried using Better Display to force the setting become 1980x1080(normal) with 50kHz, but it's still having very low resolution. Is there any way to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "unacceptable as words and picture are hard to see"? In what ways hard to see? Your monitor is a low res display (1920x1080) which is not likely to look great on a Mac.

Comment: @Gilby then in what spec it will be consider as high res display on Mac?

Comment: Macs look best with a display around 220 pixels per inch (ppi). Your display is about half that. You can only change that by get another monitor.  A 4K 24" screen is about 220 ppi and will look good at "looks like" 1980x1080.  Many people use 4K 27" monitors (at "looks" like 2560x1440) which may not be quite as good as a 5K 27" (220 ppi) screen, but are a lot cheaper.